# In C how do I break a multiple word string stored in a variable into an array with each word holding an array value

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing

What I am looking to do is have a users input of multiple words which is currently in one variable split apart and each of the words stored in an array value.

For example a user types input of: "When in the course"
and it's stored in a single variable "input"

How do I get each word of that variable into an array like such:

```
array[0] = When
array[1] = in
array[2] = the
array[3] = course
etc.
```

My end goal is to be able to run an if statement against the first word typed and use it to determine the course of action for what follows.

For example the user types: ADD when in the course

and I run an if statement against it:

```
if array[0] = ADD
then  file_ptr = fopen ("file1.txt", "a+");

            fprintf(file_ptr, "%s" , buf," ");
                    }
            fclose(file_ptr);
else if array[0] = delete
```

then delete etc.

Thank you guys for the assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question very well, but I would start with this function first, so you can split your string:

> The C library function char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)
>   breaks string str into a series of tokens using the delimiter delim.

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)
```

> Parameters str -- The contents of this string are modified and broken
>   into smaller strings (tokens).
>
> delim -- This is the C string containing the delimiters. These may
>   vary from one call to another.

[source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)

Comment: @ff210327 try to improve your question, maybe there is more I can do to help.

Comment: Actually I think that helps quite a bit.

To clarify, I'm trying to take a variable that contains multiple words and break each of the words into it's own array location array[0], array[1] etc.


So that later in the program I can run an if statement against the first array value and depending on the word that the user typed in execute a different function.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `strtok` at the beginning. I know this is a lot of code, but I wrote it showing you how to correctly manage dynamic allocated memory and how to correctly use functions like `strtok` and `realloc`, because you see a lot of wrong usage of these functions.

Of course you can make it better with more performance, but like I said, I wanted to show you more how to use dynamic allocated memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *copy_str(const char *str)
{
    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *ptr = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if(ptr)
    {
        strcpy(ptr, str);
        return ptr;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char **add_new_word(char **words, char *newword)
{
    int len;
    for(len=0; words && words[len]; ++len);

    char **tmp = realloc(words, (sizeof *words)*(len + 2));
    if(tmp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    tmp[len] = newword;
    tmp[len+1] = NULL;
    return tmp;
}


char **get_words(const char *sentence)
{
    char **strings = NULL, **tmp_strings;
    char *tmp_sentence = copy_str(sentence);
    char *tmp_sentence_orig = tmp_sentence;
    if(tmp_sentence == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char *tmp_word = copy_str(strtok(tmp_sentence, " "));
    if(tmp_word == NULL)
    {
        free(tmp_sentence_orig);
        return NULL;
    }

    tmp_strings = add_new_word(strings, tmp_word);
    if(tmp_strings == NULL)
    {
        free(tmp_sentence_orig);
        return NULL;
    }
    strings = tmp_strings;

    while(tmp_word = copy_str(strtok(NULL, " ")))
    {
        tmp_strings = add_new_word(strings, tmp_word);
        if(tmp_strings == NULL)
        {
            free(tmp_word);
            free(tmp_sentence_orig);
            return strings; // got all words we could
        }
        strings = tmp_strings;
    }

    free(tmp_sentence_orig);
    return strings;
}

void free_words(char **words)
{
    if(words == NULL)
        return;

    int i;
    for(i=0; words[i]; ++i)
        free(words[i]);

    free(words);
}

int main(void)
{
    char **words = get_words("When in the course");

    if(words == NULL)
        return 1;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; words[i]; ++i)
        printf("word #%d: '%s'\n", i+1, words[i]);

    free_words(words);
    return 0;
}
```

as you can see from `valgrind`:

```
==31202== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31202== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31202== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31202== Command: ./a
==31202==
word #1: 'When'
word #2: 'in'
word #3: 'the'
word #4: 'course'
==31202==
==31202== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31202==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31202==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 150 bytes allocated
==31202==
==31202== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31202==
==31202== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31202== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: I see how that's working with a static assignment to the array, how would it work if the user input is variable?

 
You put 
    char **words = get_words("When in the course");

What if i just have a user input that's already in it's own variable?

Comment: What do you mean by static assignment? Whether you use a string literal (like in my example) or a variable with the string doesn't change how `get_words` work, for the compiler there is no difference between these two (actually there is but is more where in memory they get allocated).  You could declare main so: `int main(int argc, char** argv)` and then call it `get_words(argv[1])` and it would work. Also making `char line[1024]; fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);char **words = get_words(line)` would work. Just try it.